# MongoDB updateOne subarray - $elemMatch doesn't work in arrayFilter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update a specific element by its id in a subarray of a document.

I use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/). If I directly specify the id in the arrayFilter with `{"members1.id":"311129357362135041"}` it modifies it as expected:

```
> db.guilds.updateOne({id:"561235799233003551"}, {$set: {"members.$[members1]": {test:"hi"}}}, {upsert: true, arrayFilters: [{"members1.id":"311129357362135041"}]})
> { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

but if I try to match the element with `{"members1":{$elemMatch: {id:"311129357362135041"}}}` it doesn't update/find the element:

```
> db.guilds.updateOne({id:"561235799233003551"}, {$set: {"members.$[members1]": {id:"311129357362135041"}}}, {upsert: true, arrayFilters: [{"members1":{$elemMatch: {id:"311129357362135041"}}}]})
> { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Why is that or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please add test data to the question.

Comment: Well because it was already the value you're trying to update. So nothing is modified. But there is no point using `elemMatch` when is equivalent to not having it.

Comment: no, in fact I used different value for $set: ``{test:"hi"}`` and ``{id:"311129357362135041"}``. 
Why is there no point using elemMatch?
If I use {"members.id": "somevalue"} its equivalent to $elemMatch: {"id": "somevalue"}?


https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/
here is an excerpt of where to find it: https://i.imgur.com/HMQ8ToM.png